# Finding an error in a function in VB

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, vb.net-2010

I am trying to call a function in one class from another on a Timer.Elapsed. I can call test functions just fine, but when I call the actual function I want, I get no exceptions, but the function just doesn't run. I have tried adding in some error handling (Catch ex) and outputting frequent messages to a .txt file to see where it fails, but I am not getting any of these messages in my log when I know that the function I am using to write these messages to the log is working.

How can I find where my function contains an error if I have no access to error messages?

Adding my code below - this is my write to log function.

```
Public Shared Function Output_To_Log(ByVal message As String) As String

    Dim strDate As String = Now.ToString("dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss ")
    Dim strTodayDate As String = Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd")

    Dim file As New FileStream("C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\logs\Log" & strTodayDate & ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim stream As New StreamWriter(file)
    stream.WriteLine(message & " : " & strDate)
    stream.Close()

    Return ""

End Function
```

This is my Timer elapsed function.

```
Private Shared Sub Timer1_Elapsed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed

    Output_To_Log("Working")

    PHJones.Start_Batch()

End Sub
```

This is my Start_Batch function, with references to my server blanked out with ****

```
Public Shared Function Start_Batch() As Integer
    Try

        Dim a As New running_check
        a.check = 1

        Dim files As String()
        Dim File As String
        Dim myProcess As New Diagnostics.Process()
        Dim File_Name As String
        Dim Running_FileName As String

        RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Start_Batch starting")

Start:
        RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Checking logs")
        Dim log_check As Integer = check_logs()

        RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Getting .DAT files.")
        files = IO.Directory.GetFiles("****\phjones\to_phjones\", "*.DAT")

        If files.Count > 0 Then
            RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Counted " & files.Count & " files.")
        Else
            RunTimer.Output_To_Log("No files found.")
        End If

        For Each File In files
            Try
                RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Starting process for " & File)
                Running_FileName = File & ".BAT"
                RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Processing " & Running_FileName)

                File_Name = File.Substring(26)

                If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files\" & File_Name & ".BAT") Then
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log("C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files\" & File_Name & ".BAT already exists")
                Else
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Copying " & Running_FileName & " to batch_files folder")
                    System.IO.File.Copy(Running_FileName, "C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files\" & File_Name & ".BAT", True)
                End If

                If (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files\" & File_Name & ".BAT")) Then
                    If (System.IO.File.Exists(Running_FileName)) Then
                        RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Deleting file " & Running_FileName)
                        System.IO.File.Delete(Running_FileName)
                    Else
                        RunTimer.Output_To_Log(File_Name & ".BAT does not exist in ****\phjones\to_phjones\processed")
                    End If
                Else
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log(File_Name & ".BAT failed to copy")
                    Throw New Exception(File_Name & ".BAT failed to copy to C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files")
                End If

                RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Executing batch file " & Running_FileName)
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\PHJones_Windows_Service\Batch_Files\" & File_Name & ".BAT"
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
                myProcess.Start()
                myProcess.WaitForExit()

                If System.IO.File.Exists("****\phjones\to_phjones\" & File_Name) Then
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log("****\phjones\to_phjones\" & File_Name & " already exists")
                    System.IO.File.Delete(File)
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log(File & " has been deleted")
                Else
                    RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Moving " & File)
                    System.IO.File.Move(File, "****\phjones\to_phjones\" & File_Name)
                End If

                Dim IWCnn = New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)

                Dim intRepair_Id As Integer = Mid(File_Name, 1, 7)
                Dim intRepair_seq As Integer = Mid(File_Name, 8, 1)

                RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Updating database for file " & File)
                IWCnn.Open()
                Dim StatusCmd As New OracleCommand("update works_orders " & _
                                    "set wor_sco_code = 'ISS', wor_issued_datetime = sysdate" & _
                                    " where wor_srq_no = " & intRepair_Id & _
                                    " and wor_seqno  = " & intRepair_seq, IWCnn)
                StatusCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                IWCnn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception

                RunTimer.Timer1.Enabled = False

                RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Exception thrown in PHJones 2010 - " & ex.Message)



                Thread.Sleep(900000)
                RunTimer.Timer1.Enabled = True

                a.check = 0

                Return 0

            End Try
        Next

        a.check = 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Exception thrown in PHJones 2010 - " & ex.Message)
    End Try


    Return 0


End Function
```

The entire RunTimer class.

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Configuration.Install


Public Class RunTimer

Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

Friend Shared WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer

Public Counter As Integer = 0

Public Sub New()

    MyBase.New()
    InitializeComponents()

End Sub



Private Sub InitializeComponents()

    Me.ServiceName = "RunTimer"
    Me.AutoLog = True
    Me.CanStop = True
    Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer()
    Timer1.Interval = 15000
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub



' This method starts the service.

<MTAThread()> Shared Sub Main()

    ' To run more than one service you have to add them to the array

    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New RunTimer})

End Sub



' Clean up any resources being used.

Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)

    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)

    ' TODO: Add cleanup code here (if required)

End Sub



Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

    ' TODO: Add start code here (if required) to start your service.

    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub



Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()

    ' TODO: Add tear-down code here (if required) to stop your service.
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Output_To_Log("Ended")

End Sub


Private Sub InitializeComponent()


    Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer

    CType(Timer1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()

    Timer1.Enabled = True

    CType(Timer1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()

End Sub

Private Shared Sub Timer1_Elapsed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed

    Output_To_Log("Working")

    PHJones.Start_Batch()

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some code. It's impossible for us to solve this without it.

Comment: I have done that now.

Comment: Is anything at all printed to your logfile? For example "Working"?

Comment: Working is printed, but it never outputs "Start_Batch starting", leading me to beleive that the function isn't even being called correctly.

Comment: I flinched when I saw the jump label. Anyways... what kind of error do you get? `PHJones` seems to be an instance of a class (or rather it should be) could you elaborate what it is?

Comment: PHJones is a class, and Start_Batch is just a function within that class. This is the thing - I don't get an error messages or exceptions - it just doesn't run.

Comment: I've tried to setup the skeleton for this. And for me the function is called. Can you show the code for the initialization of the Timer? That includes Construct, AddHandler, Enabling the timer.

Comment: I will add my entire RunTimer Class to the main question.

Comment: Where does Output_To_Log go?  I don't see it in the RunTimer class

Comment: This works for me if I call it from a Form. Are you trying to execute this as a Service?

Comment: This is being executed as a service, yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. Output to Log is used in the Timer1_Elapsed Sub and the Start_Batch Function to write messages to a log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running as a service, you won't see ordinary error messages. It's possible there is an error between `Output_To_Log("Working")` in the Timer event and `RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Start_Batch starting")` of `Start_Batch()`. For example, if an error could occur in the initialization of `Dim a As New running_check`, or in the call itself, `PHJones.Start_Batch()`. Either of these would cause what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not at work anymore, so I cant confirm this until Friday, but if I recall then if the first line of the function was an Outpu_to_Log, it still failed. What are the possbile reasons for a function being called to fail?

Comment: An error error could occur when you initialize an instance of a  class, for example, "Dim a As New running_check" or "Dim myProcess As New Diagnostics.Process()". Or maybe the error occurs in the call to PHJones.Start_Batch(). Is "PHJones." correct?

Comment: Im fairly sure PHJones is correct, I will have to check the running_check etc as soon as I am back at work. Thank you.

Comment: So even when I put a Try around all other code, and before that try is `RunTimer.Output_To_Log("Start_Batch starting")` and that is the first line in the function, nothing is output to the log. As far as I can see, something is causing my `PHJones.Start_Batch()` function to not be called, but I cannot see what.

Comment: Right, so if I comment out all my `Start_Batch()` code other than the `Output_to_log`, it works correctly. This must mean that something in my function is broken, causing it to be called incorrectly. I ma currently going through my code line by line to find out what.

Comment: It ended up being a mismatch between Framework versions installed on the live server and my local machine. Thanks for all the help, it was the call itself that was erroring as the call tried to reference something that didn't exist. I ended up putting a `Try...Catch` around `PhJones.StartBatch()` in the Timer1_Elapsed sub, which found the error for me.